# SwiftUI: Put String array into a single Text, with offset on every second member of the array

Tags: arrays, string, foreach, swiftui, reduce

I'm pretty new to Swift, and to coding in general. My goal is, to put chords above the lyrics of a song. I managed to separate the chords from the lyrics, with a separator:

```
let lyrics = "|C|Alszik a szív és |E|alszik a szívben az |Am|aggodalom,\n\n|C|Alszik a pókhá|E|ló közelében a |Am|légy a falon."

let lyricsArray = lyrics.components(separatedBy: "|")
```

So now every even indexed member of the array is a *chord*, and every odd indexed member of the array is a *lyrics snippet*.

What I can't figure out, how to put every even indexed member of the array above the rest of the array. My desired output would be like this: [Image of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fclq2.png)

I tried doing a ForEach:

```
ForEach(lyricsArray, id: \.self) {
   Text("\($0)")
}
```

This way, there is a new Text for every member of the array with line breaks.

I also tried reduce:

```
lyricsArray.reduce(Text(""), { $0 + Text($1)} )
```

This is much closer to what I want to see, but from here, I don't know, how could I put an ".offset(x: 0, y: -30)" to every second member of the array.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct LyricsView: View {
    let lyrics = "|C|Alszik a szív és |E|alszik a szívben az |Am|aggodalom,\n\n|C|Alszik a pókhá|E|ló közelében a |Am|légy a falon."
    ///Separates into lines
    var linesArray: [String]{
        lyrics.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")
    }
    ///Separates lines into notes
    var notesArray: [[String]]{
        var notes: [[String]] = []
        for line in linesArray{
            notes.append(line.components(separatedBy: "|"))
        }
        return notes
    }
    var body: some View {
        List{
            //Iterate through the Array of String Arrays /lines
            ForEach(notesArray, id: \.self) {line in
                HStack{
                    //Iterate through indices
                    //The - 1 is to account for the last value that would have already been used when you iterate through. You would get index out of bounds below
                    ForEach(0..<line.count - 1, id: \.self) {n in
                        if n % 2 == 1{//Check even odd
                            VStack(alignment: .center){
                                Text(line[n])
                                //This line would give you the index out of bounds
                                Text(line[n + 1])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is much closer than anything I tried so far! :) Still, it has line breaks after every member of the array. I would like to have line breaks on the lyrics only where I put "\n". Like on the picture of the original post. Do you have any ideas, how could I work that out? Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Just separate the lines before the notes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You saved me a lot of time and frustration! :)